# changing the color of the text in an c# application when i change the computer

Tags: c#

I have created an application in c # visual studio, I set the text color to blue.
When I opened the application in another computer the text color was changed to black

any ideas please. thanks.

Comment: Provide to us code where you change color of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Were they using different operating systems?

Also the 'theme' that is in use on that PC will effect the color of some components.

For example if you set a color of a component in your application to be `ActiveCaption` you may find that another PC will have a different color for active captions.

**If you want to look at specific values such as R,G,B then create a set of local variables that you could watch during debug, or write to file for each machine.**

Example:

```
Byte acR = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaption.R;
Byte acG = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaption.G;
Byte acB = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ActiveCaption.B;
```

Comment: how can I know how ActiveCaption color is calculated in each machine. thanks

Comment: If you explicitly set the color, different theme might not influence that? As local setting has higher priority, is this the case?

Comment: As Daniil has mentioned above, show us how you set the color and we can then analyse where there may be an issue.

Comment: I set the color of the menu ActiveCaption, but by opening the application in another computer color became dark, I wanted to know how I can detect the color of Active Caption in each machine to understand the behavior of the display color

Comment: Updated Post To Reflect Request